# Error on mean from measurements made from a distribution with a possible long tail

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval

I am using Langevin dynamics simulations to measure a first hitting time of particles leaving a region in parameter space. I would like to measure the mean first hitting time (and not the median for example) because after making some simplifying assumptions, I can calculate the mean of the first hitting time explicitly (but not the whole distribution), and want to compare this with data to test whether those simplifying assumptions put me in the right ball park.

My problem is that the mean first hitting time measured from my simulation seems to increase with the time that I run for (more time means more trajectories/samples used in calculating this mean). Between a run of length $T$ and a run of length $\sim 1.2T$, the mean increased by more than 3 standard errors. A similar increase exists between a run of length $\sim 0.8T$ and $T$. So the tail of the empirical distribution seems to affect the mean, and there seems to be a systematic underestimation of both the mean and the standard error, which made me wonder about a long tailed distribution. However theoretically it is impossible for a set of non-zero measure of trajectories to remain inside the region forever, therefore the mean time of exit must be finite.

The histogram of my current samples looks like this, the average is ~1.4:
[image]

I am limited in computational power as to how long I can run my simulation for. I expect that if I were to continue to run my simulations, the mean would eventually asymptotically reach some value, however this is not yet visible from my current samples. Given the data that I have, is there a way to generate the confidence intervals on my current mean to ensure that this asymptotic value is included in the interval?

A few more details about the simulation/system: The region the particles are escaping from is inhomogenous and has other occupants, so theoretically it is a black box where not much can be done theoretically other than the few simplifying assumptions I am trying to test out. Multiple particles are escaping at the same time, however they interact minimally with each other and their density inside the region is low, so low chances of encountering another particle. Therefore the exit times of two particles is not exactly independent, but any correlations between the times of two particles will be extremely weak. The system is also at steady state, so on average there is the same number of particles inside the region for all times.

Comment: Could you explain how you generate this quantity?  I imagine it has to be indirectly. If it were generated directly in a simulation you would have to randomly select from a "known" distribution.

Comment: The quantity is the time it takes for a system to leave a region of space after it has entered (first hitting time). During the simulation, multiple systems wander around until the enter and then leave this region, which generates the samples.

Comment: Are the samples iid? Are they independent?

Comment: Yes to both of those

Comment: Molecular dynamics. Sometimes a molecule may wander around a bit and then suddenly make a big jump. So, the bad news is that you probably may need more computation time and model the molecules over longer time scales to capture the bahaviour of the system correctly (I would not use first hitting time but just look at the mean movement, or use other ways to capture more information per single simulation).

Comment: You want to capture those irregular jumps and indeed a few trials may not show this behavior but then suddenly an increase of the sample may add one of the examples from the tail and change the sample mean drastically. You may wonder whether the mean is a good measure to characterize the movement of molecules on short timescales. It is probably what you are finaly interested (large timescale behaviour) in and likely it is finite (or diffusion rate would be infinite) but it is not what works at short timescales.

Comment: If you want to reduce the computation needs and use a small sample then you would need some kind of theory (knowledge) about the distribution in order to connect more than just the mean of the small sample to the parameters of the distribution. Asking about this on the physics.stackexchange website could help.

Comment: Could you describe more about your simulations.

Comment: My timesteps are such that molecules should not move more than 0.1nm in a single timestep, which is two orders of magnitude smaller than the size of my regions, so I'm not worried about large errors there.

Comment: Sorry, it's not actually molecular dynamics, but Langevin dynamics with high damping, that is why I don't expect large jumps on the order of magnitude of my regions of interest.

Comment: Please provide more information. There are too many questions and open ends. For instance? 1) How large is your current sample and how does it's distribution look like based on a histogram (I suspect something close to an exponential distribution) 2) Why do you compute the residence time so directly? (You might be able to assume ergodicity and use a shortcut by dividing 'the average number of particles/systems in the region of space' by 'the frequency of particles/systems leaving the region of space'.) 3) Are any of those two numbers also heavily tailed and difficult to sample?

Comment: My current sample is ~1000 first hitting times. The histogram looks something like an exponential by eye. In this case it's not safe to assume ergodicity. My preference is to be able to say something about the mean first hitting time and its error, if that turns out to not be possible, I will certainly look at other options, but I think that's beyond the scope of this question. I currently don't have access to the frequency of particles leaving the region of space.

Comment: By how much did the mean increase? Could you plot the histogram? What is the rate parameter if you would fit an exponential distribution to the observations? Etc... Without any information and background we can not say *anything* about the sample mean and how well it can be an estimate for the hitting time (except asymptotically the sample mean should follow a normal distribution). It is also unclear *what* your observations are and by how much your observations are peculiar (a change of the sample mean over time, outside some range of error determined by an earlier sample, is not strange).

Comment: Why does it need to be the mean? Would median be useful? Can you estimate the distribution of the outcome? If a parametric approximation was close enough some relevant answers may be more obvious.

Comment: Rereading the comments, you need to edit your question to include a lot of those details. If exponential doesn't fit the distribution, then Weibull distribution may be relevant, both are common time to event distributions (exponential is special case where shape parameter is 1)

Comment: Let me ask again: Are your samples iid?  You say that several systems move around, and you measure the time they spend in a given region of space.  If these several systems move simultaneously and if you combine their times, then their times are *not independent*.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I have edited my question with more detail to hopefully address all your points from the comments. Please let me know if there is anything else that I missed which might be important.

Comment: What's the relationship between the 'time' used to run the simulation and the 'first hitting time'? Are you running one simulation of many particles and counting the hitting times from that one simulation? E.g. is the simulation such that if you simulate for time $1.2\,T$, it is impossible to observe first hitting times longer than $1.2\,T$?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Although for the histogram I plotted, $T$ is ~30, while the longest first hitting time is ~6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior that the mean keeps increasing when more samples are added, typically means that the mean time is infinite. You could for example be facing a [pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) with $\alpha\le 1$.

You may not be facing this exact distribution, but it is the most standard example of a fairly simple distribution with infinite mean, so it is worth taking a look at; and it will have the same behavior as you are describing: it only takes finite values (mostly 1 or slightly above) so the mean of any finite sample will be finite, but it will grow as the number of samples grows.

To fortify my argument, I will explain why your "I expect that if I were to continue to run my simulations, the mean would eventually asymptotically reach some value" must be wrong. Let's say your mean after the first $n$ simulations is $\mu_1$, and after the first $2n$ simulations it is $\mu_2<\mu_1$. Then, the mean among simulations $n+1,\ldots,2n$ was $\mu_3=2\mu_2-\mu_1<\mu_2$, meaning we have $\mu_3<\mu_2<\mu_1$. However, since your simulations are independent, $E[\mu_3]=E[\mu_1]$, hence you cannot consistently find this behavior if the mean was finite and well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

The difference of the empirical means of two sets of samples might well be larger than the standard error of the mean. Asymptotically, the standard error defines a confidence interval to the level 0.67 or so.
If the distribution has long tails and the sample mean is unstable, the sample standard deviation should be large. As long as the underlying distribution has a well-defined mean and variance, things should work out more or less.
Finally, if the sample mean is unstable, maybe it makes more sense to estimate and report a more robust measure of location, such as the median.

Comment: The difference of the empirical means of two sets of samples might well be larger than the standard error of the mean, but it is not possible that the estimated mean keeps growing as more samples are added, unless the mean is infinite, which appears to be the case here. See my answer for further details.

Comment: I agree,and that's why I voted for your answer. Note that the OP edited his answers and expanded his description after I gave my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your problem may be more related to your field of study (say, molecular dynamics) than statistics. Statistics deals with probability distribution of random variables and, it does not matter what your distribution is, for applying central limit theorem, for making inferences about population (with large samples). However, since you have mentioned that such simulation does not work in your case with mean changing randomly every time, it is quite possible that the 'time spent in the region' may be a random variable with no finite mean at all (for example, a random normal distribution assumes that, even though the variable is random, the variable will tend towards a central value i.e. mean, so is the case with other known standard distributions which mimic some natural phenomenon). But if the 'time spent' variable is completely random, whose value is affected by other variables in your model, you cannot expect 'any mean value' whatever time you spend in simulation. For example, movement of stock prices over a time interval are completely random in nature, and it cannot be modeled under any known probability distribution and it cannot have any mean related to it.

If your theory, however, indicates that there should be finite mean for time spent (which I intuit very unlikely for molecular movements) and if you are sure about it, then you should work on finding out the distribution function and its moment generating functions etc., to arrive at the mean function.

Note: If finite mean is a sure theoretical possibility, another statistically sound method to estimate the mean is MLE estimation methods (especially in data science paradigm). But, MLE methods, that estimate population parameters, mandatorily require an assumption about the nature of population distribution and its density function (which is not required for CLT based inferential statistics that makes inferences on sample). But there could be other techniques available in data science paradigm, which could estimate population parameters, but they may rely on quantitative and computationally intensive algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

If the mean is changing significantly when you add more data then you may not have a finite mean or not unimodal. hist(c(rnorm(100, 0, 1) + rnorm(100, 3, 1)))`. But I'm guessing you've already made a histogram of your data or have been able to visualize it. So Here's what I would do. 1.) Calculate the mean with an increasing number of data samples. The more you can do the better but only do what is feasible. 2.) Look to see if the means follow some type of infinite series that converge. Maybe a geometric series, p-series or something like that. If you can find that the mean follows some kind of pattern like $const.\frac{n}{n+1}$ would be a simple one. Even if you're mean is moving up and down and it doesn't seem to follow a pattern you may have $-1^{i}$ in the sequence or something similar.

I hope this is a little closer to what you were looking for.

When you say simulations I'm assuming that you are either running Monte Carlo simulations or constructing bootstrap samples. Either way here is what you want to do. 
1. run b simulations
2. during each bth simulation draw a random sample that is the size of the data set with replacement. 
3. Calculate the mean of the sample drawn. 
4. The simulation is complete so now you have an array with b sample means. Take the mean of that array and this is your mean. You can also create credible regions (when you run a simulation confidence intervals no longer apply because your regions are empirical).

```
B <- 1000
n <- dim(data)[1]
ind <- seq_len(n)
means_vector <- double(B)
for ( b in seq_len(B)) {
    rand_samp <- sample(ind, n, replace = TRUE)
means_vector[B] <- mean(data[rand_samp])
}
mean(means_vector)
quantile(means_vector, c(0.25, 0.975))
```

This is the bootstrap method. It's pretty simple, and there's an R function "boot()" that will make things crazy fast.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this is different to what I am currently doing. I am actually running molecular dynamics simulations, and the longer I run these for, the larger my data set. My current problem is that as my data set increases, my mean goes up, presumably because my data set is including more samples from the long tail of the distribution. I'm not sure how bootstrapping within the data set I currently have will take care of the long tail.